# procedure to run perl scripts on Amazon Web Services

Tags: perl, amazon-web-services

I am newbie to AWS. I have perl scripts currently which are running in UNIX server. But due to some server issues we just wanted to run these scripts in AWS. Can anybody tell the procedure to run the scripts in AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Get an EC2 (unix server) on AWS under "Free tier".

copy your perl scripts on that server and you are good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After getting EC2 , can you please tell how to proceed in some detailed manner?

Comment: ssh to that machine using the key ; and copy your perl script there.. and run it